# How to refresh strings in asp.net application from resources?

Tags: .net, resources, localization

We are having some very strange problem with .NET resources in our .NET 2.0 framework ASP.NET application.

We have a list or resources in App_GlobalResources directory. When I change the contents of resources (e.g. change the string) in the .resx then the change is not immediately visible on the website.

The obvious step is to restart web application using IIS or dummy change in web.config file but it does not work.

What is more suprising even triggering IISRESET does not solve the issue. What simply happens is after few hours the change is refereshed.

How can I force to update the website immediately?

(to clear other obvious problems, I tried clearing browser cache, using multiple browsers etc - its not a client issue)

Comment: Also, I would like to add that we have a failover server for this web app where the resources are refreshed immediately without problems. We cannot figure out what differences in configuration of these servers can be causing this problem on our live server

Comment: What you are looking for is a way to force resource recompilation... The most obvious and brutal would be to remove compiled binaries (I am not sure if it is even possible). There must be some other way but unfortunately I don't know the answer...